# use ajax to bind/rebind a listview datasource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

Is it possible to bind/rebind a RadListView's datasource using Ajax? What I'm trying to do is create a type of forum. One ListView is nested in another listview. The outer listview will load on page load and display all of the subject headers, and the innerlist view will not be bound until the header is clicked. Then I'll use jQuery to open the details under the header and load THAT ListView using ajax. is this possible and how? or is there another way I should into achieving this effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the outer list in an `UpdatePanel` and assign an `OnClick` handler to the subject line. When the subject line is clicked, an async postback will occur and you can bind the inner list in the click event handler.

One way or another you need to get to the code-behind. If you want to use jQuery, you can attach click events to the header and call __doPostBack in the handler, like this:

```
$("#<%=ListView1.ClientID%> .header").click(function(){
    __doPostBack($(this).attr("id"), "");
});
```

If you go with this approach, you'll just need to override the `RaisePostBackEvent` in the code-behind, and use a little logic to drill down to the inner list.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way if you do not care about doing a PostBack would be to wire up the nested ListViews, and have the header hook to the  ItemCommand event and bind the applicable RadListView that you need, and hide others. You could possibly disable the ViewState on these controls to keep the size down, since you would only be showing the currently selected items ListView, if you will not be doing any paging or sorting.

For a faster postback, you can loook at Client Side Databinding for RadListView

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/client/programmaticdatabinding/defaultcs.aspx

You would generate a function that you can send the ListView's ClientID to databind as well as the Outer div (if you need one) to show when clicking the header.

The function would then find the ListView, show the outer container, and databind it. You could possibly also include code that would collapse the currently visible div, if you desire that functionality. A global variable saving the previous div's ID would be an easy way for it to work.